# If a class is marked as @Transactional, could the usual transaction management boilerplate code be omitted?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

If a class is marked as @Transactional, does that mean that the boilerplate:

```
Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();

  try {
   ...
   ...
   ...
   tx.commit();


  }

  catch (Exception e) {
   tx.rollBack();
  }
```

can be omitted? My Hibernate-based code certainly works without it.

**EDIT (FOLLOW UP):** Then why do people keep writing the boilerplate within their methods, even when they have their classes annotated?

Comment: To answer your last question: for the same reason one third of the questions on SO can be answered by just reading the f*** documentation: developers are unable or too lazy to read the documentation nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as long as

1. Transaction management is properly configured, see [13.3.3 Declarative transaction demarcation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)
2. Calls to that method don't violate limitations of AOP-based declarative transaction management, see [10.5.1 Understanding the Spring Framework's declarative transaction implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-strategies) (or you use advanced features such as AspectJ integration to overcome these limitations).
   That is, all calls to that method are performed on an object obtained from Spring, and no calls are performed from another methods of the same class.
3. `Session` is obtained inside a method by calling `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it's the main goal of the declarative transactions notion.
Moreover, it's more flexible so that you can use different propagation levels to combine several methods in transactions.

Comment: Then why do people keep writing the boilerplate within their methods, even when they have their classes annotated?

Comment: An obsolete code. Or just they don't read documentation, or just don't understand, or afraid of using it, or... In short, there is no rational reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you also have `<tx:annotation-driven/>`, yes--that's what the annotation is for :)

[The docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) go in to great detail.